# Вёрстка сетки товаров

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я начинающий верстальщик сайтов, столкнулся с проблемой при вёрстке карточек товара.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.product-wrap {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px; 
  font-family: Lora;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.product-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.product-wrap img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.product-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.button { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c0a97a;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #c0a97a;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.button:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.product-item:hover .product-buttons {opacity: 1;}
.product-item:hover .button {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);}
.button:hover {background: black;}
.product-title {color: #5e5e5e;}
.product-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 15px 0 5px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.product-title a:after{    
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #2e2e2e;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.product-title a:hover {color: #c0a97a;}
.product-title:hover a:after {background: #c0a97a;}
.product-price {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #c0a97a;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-wrap">
  <div class="product-item">
    <img src="source/img/test.png">
    <div class="product-buttons">
      <a href="#" class="button">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-title">
    <a href="">Test</a>
    <span class="product-price">₽ 100</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

У меня получается карточка.  (скриншот прикреплён)
[image: Скриншот]

Хотелось бы узнать как мне сделать так, чтобы следующая шла с право от неё. Если просто скопировать HTML код, то она остаётся на месте.

И как мне сделать так, чтобы когда место справа не осталось, карточка переместилась на следующий ряд.

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: вы оберните их каким то блоком и этому блоку напишите `display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;`

Comment: А нафига у вас `position: absolute` здесь стоит?

Answer (score 1):

Убрать position:absolute; и использовать для .product-wrap свойство float: left; и будет тебе счастье. Или display: inline-block;. Или обернуть всё это в еще один блок и задать ему display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;.

> Если просто скопировать HTML код, то она остаётся на месте.

Она не остается на месте. Она располагается поверх существующей карточки. Это можно будет увидеть в консоли. Происходит это из-за абсолютного позиционирования.

Если хочется разобраться в том, какое свойство за что отвечает, добро пожаловать куда-нибудь на https://webref.ru/css

Я бы рекомендовал 1 раз всю справку прочитать, не особо заучивая, а потом уже браться что-то верстать. Когда будут возникать проблемы, в памяти начнут всплывать мысли в стили "Что-то подобное я читал и называлось оно вроде-бы как-то так."